# .toggle() prevents Envira Gallery to load properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, toggle

I've got the following Problem. I got a link that opens a Envira-Gallery (Wordpress-Plugin) via .toggle(). But the script of the gallery-plugin doesn't execute to the end so the images won't arrange properly.

Here's the part with .toggle():

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#r_gartenbaushow").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#r_gartenbau").toggle();
   window.location.hash = "r_gartenbau";
  });
  $("#r_gartenbauhide").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#r_gartenbau").toggle();
  });
  $("#r_gartenbau").hide();
});});
```

I added the window.bind and document.ready so at least some part of the galleryscript is working but not till the end.

Here is the demo-site: http://demo.renzen-communications.ch/spross.com/garten-und-landschaftsbau/#referenzen

Click on one of the green boxes to open the gallery.

Sometimes the gallery gets fully loaded and on a second refresh it won't :(

Can somebody help me?

Comment: btw if I open the Firefox Developer Tools (righ click + Q) when the not fully loaded gallery is open it arranges the images correctly. It does some kind of refresh?

Comment: There's a important error in your console - 'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'  if you take care of that, things might run as they should. The error is saying that you're calling a jQuery function, before jQuery itself is loaded.

Comment: Hi @Andrew-ThinkUp that's strange because jQuery is called in the <head> so before the gallery :P

Comment: fixed the uncaught  typeerror still the same problem :( think just the gallery plugin doesnt load correctly :/